# popup html page reloads parent page with a lag

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have a problem with reloading parent pages in Javascript.

When I open popup window with a form and submit it (first try), the parent page reloads but with old data.

When I do this again with another value (second try), the parent page does show a change in data, but it shows PREVIOUSLY sumbitted value from the first try.

When I make the third try and submit the third value, the parent page reloads and shows the second value.

And so on, and so forth. So there's this lag.

What's more, this only works in Chrome (for Mac). In Safari and Firefox the form isn't even submitted. The data stays the same no matter how many times I submit the popup form.

What's going on, and how to fix it?

The link to the popup window:

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('/add-payment/16','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">550</a>`

and the popup window itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function dothesubmit(){
        paymentform=document.getElementById('addpayment');
        paymentform.submit();
        window.opener.location.href="http://localhost:5000/editsupplement/10";
        window.close();
}
</script>    

<form id="addpayment" action="/add-payment/16" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sum">
    <button type="submit" onclick="dothesubmit();">Save</button>
</form>      

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reloading the parent page too soon. You should wait for the form submit to finish first before reloading the parent page.
You can submit the form via ajax, wait for the request to complete, and only then reload the parent page and close the popup.

```
$('#addpayment').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: this.getAttribute('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json'
    }).always(function(data){
        window.opener.location.href="http://localhost:5000/editsupplement/10";
        window.close();
    });
})
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tyb2gy2d/3/